# JavaScript Regular Expression Help - Limiting number of matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to limit the number of results from a string. An example string I'm working with is:

```
2013        910       1102          0        203        398
```

Rather than using a match array, I'd like the regular expression to match only the first three digits. These happen to be memory usage, so the numbers could be smaller or larger.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean by "smaller" that there could also sometimes be only 1 or 2 digits?

Comment: Yes. These are memory logs. That first number could be 512, or it could be 32000. I'm attempting to use regex to only capture whatever the first three numbers are though. I want it to ignore any numbers after the first three. I can of course use match and a \d{1,} expression but I'm attempting to generalize due to applying this elsewhere.

edit: free -t -m | grep Mem: | grep [0-999999] is what I'm using to get the infomration. If there's a way to use grep to limit it to the first three results there that would accomplish the same. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You can use regexp with grep aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just match from the beginning of the string and then the next three digits. Like this:

```
^\d{3}
```

Where:

```
^ = start of string
\d = digit 0-9
{3} = Three of the tokens
```

EDIT:

With the extra requirements this should help you out:

```
^(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+)
```

This will capture the first three groups of digits.

Comment: var num = '2013        910       1102          0        203        398';
var re = /^\d{3}/;

var a = num.match(re);

console.log(a);


this returns 201 because it collects the first 3 digits. I need 2013 910 and 1102 returned from the regex.

Comment: You want the first three groups of numbers returned?

Comment: Exactly. I spent a lot of time googling but i couldn't find anything that helped me (or at least I didn't understand). And I played with a regex creator for hours.

Comment: Just go with (\d+). And you will get an array of matches, and just use the first three ones, 0-2.

Comment: That works fine. I'm just trying to fine tune this to only return what i'm looking for as i'm writing a generalized function that would be applied to all sorts of different data coming in. I was trying to find a way to use grep to limit what was return but I was only able to get it down to the 6 values.

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty much what I'm looking for. I couldn't figure out how to group the first 3. Now I can just access the 0 index. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Np. I'm glad to help. Next time be more specific in your original question and you will get the help you need right away.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `^(\d+)` and capture group 1.

A regex does not need to match the whole input! Just match what you need to match.

Answer (score 0):

```
"2013 910 1102 0 203 398".split(" ").slice(0,3);
```

If numbers in string are separated more than one space then you should in first make shorten them.

```
"2013     910    1102 0   203 398".replace(/\s+/g," ").split(" ").slice(0,3);
```

output will be:

```
["2013", "910", "1102"]
```

Comment: This results in the same problem as above. It's not the 201. I would like an array returned with [2013,910,1102] and none of the following.